# Convert 9 Apr 2014 20:36:13 GMT to France timezone 9 Apr 2014 21:36:13 CEST

Tags: java, android, timezone

I need to convert 9 Apr 2014 20:36:13 GMT to france timezone 9 Apr 2014 21:36:13 CEST.

i come across this function but was unable to adapt it to my code.

```
long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date localTime = new Date(ts);

        String format = "dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

        // Convert Local Time to UTC (Works Fine)
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date gmtTime = new Date(sdf.format(localTime));
        System.out.println("Local:" + localTime.toString() + "," + localTime.getTime() + " --> UTC time:"
                + gmtTime.toString() + "," + gmtTime.getTime());

        // **** YOUR CODE **** END ****

        // Convert UTC to Local Time
        Date fromGmt = new Date(gmtTime.getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(localTime.getTime()));
        System.out.println("UTC time:" + gmtTime.toString() + "," + gmtTime.getTime() + " --> Local:"
                + fromGmt.toString() + "-" + fromGmt.getTime());
```

Any idea please.

Comment: Your String format is incorrect. You should have only "MMM" for "Apr".

Comment: isn't there 2 hours diff. due to winter time?

Comment: yes i need to add 1 hour if summer time and 2 hours if winter time

Comment: I hope you know that "9 Apr 2014 21:36:13 CEST" **is one hour earlier** than "9 Apr 2014 20:36:13 GMT".

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22989630/642706) is correct.

## Joda-Time

Using the Joda-Time 2.3 library makes this work much easier.

```
String input = "9 Apr 2014 20:36:13 GMT";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z" ).withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
DateTimeZone timeZoneParis = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone( timeZoneParis ).parseDateTime( input );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
String output = formatter.withZone( timeZoneParis ).print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
input: 9 Apr 2014 20:36:13 GMT
dateTime: 2014-04-09T22:36:13.000+02:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-04-09T20:36:13.000Z
output: 9 Apr 2014 22:36:13 CEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the task is to convert one timestamp **string** to another **string** changing the timezone. Your code tries to convert `Date`-objects which is not in agreement with the task.

A `Date`-object has NO internal timezone and only refers to UTC timezone per spec. This fundamental fact is not affected by the strange and extremely confusing output of its `toString()`-method which uses default time zone. Therefore trying to convert a `Date`-object to another timezone is nonsense (it is and remains in UTC-timezone, the state is observable by its method `getTime()` which yields the elapsed milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00,000 in UTC timezone).

Regarding your input "9 Apr 2014 20:36:13 GMT" you need:

```
  // Use d, not dd for one or two day digits, use s for second, use z for timezone abbreviations
  String format = "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";

  // specify the locale and timezone for input, "Apr" sounds like English
  SimpleDateFormat formatGMT = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
  formatGMT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

  // specify the locale and timezone for output, use a valid timezone identifier (IANA)
  SimpleDateFormat formatFrance = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
  formatFrance.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));

  String input = "9 Apr 2014 20:36:13 GMT";
  Date d = formatGMT.parse(input);
  String output = formatFrance.format(d);

  // the offset in April (summer time) is TWO hours, not one
  System.out.println(output); // 9 Apr 2014 22:36:13 CEST
```

Just for the case you really mean to do date arithmetic like subtracting one hour in summer and adding one hour in winter, you need:

```
boolean summerTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris").inDaylightTime(d);
if (summerTime) {
  d = new Date(d.getTime() - 3600 * 1000L);
} else {
  d = new Date(d.getTime() + 3600 * 1000L);
}
String output = formatFrance.format(d);

In winter you get: 9 Mar 2014 22:36:13 CET (input was in March)
In summer you get: 9 Apr 2014 21:36:13 CEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. and tell me is it useful to you.

```
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    java.util.TimeZone timeZonecurr     = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT");
    java.util.TimeZone timeZoneto   = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2");

    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZonecurr);
    java.util.Calendar calendar = new java.util.GregorianCalendar(timeZonecurr);
    System.out.println("Current Time in Etc/GMT   = " +  sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

    calendar.setTimeZone(timeZoneto);
    sdf.setTimeZone(timeZoneto);
    System.out.println("Current Time in Etc/GMT+2   = " +  sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` in Java does not have a time zone attached. It represents just a point in time. Time zones come only into play if you convert between `Date` and `String` or vice versa.

This means, you just use a format bound to GMT when you read the date (convert it from a `String`to a `Date`) and later you use another format bound to France when you convert it back to a `String`.